# List of objects dissapears in the method i'm testing with Moq mocking and unittests in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, entity-framework-6

Ok i'm having trouble to form a good qeustion so please don't flame me on that what i'm trying to do in my code is moqing a list of which i get 1 object in the list. This object is retrieved by a .find method in the moqed database. It however doesn't return values because somehow in the method the data dissappears and my Person object is left with null i'll post some screenshots that will hopefully explain what i'm trying to say together with the testing method i'm using:

the method:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestDetails()
        {
            Person test = new Person();
            test.ID = 1;
            test.City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.";
            test.Name = "Marijn van Donkelaar";
            test.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "Java:7, C#:4, SQL:4, PLSQL:4, Software Documentation:4, Software Development:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1";
            test.ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg";
            test.PhoneNr = "0612345678";
            test.SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:2";
            test.Email = "fraylight@gmail.com";
            Person test1 = new Person();
            test1.ID = 2;
            test1.City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.";
            test1.Name = "Jan Pietjes";
            test1.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "Java:7, C#:4, SQL:4, PLSQL:4, Software Documentation:4, Software Development:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1";
            test1.ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg";
            test1.PhoneNr = "0612345678";
            test1.SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:2";
            test1.Email = "fraylight@gmail.com";
            Person test2 = new Person();
            test2.ID = 3;
            test2.City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.";
            test2.Name = "Jasmine Test";
            test2.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "Java:7, C#:4, SQL:4, PLSQL:4, Software Documentation:4, Software Development:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1";
            test2.ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg";
            test2.PhoneNr = "0612345678";
            test2.SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:2";
            test2.Email = "fraylight@gmail.com";

            var data = new List<Person> { test, test1, test2 }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator()); 

            var mockContext = new Mock<PersonDBContext>();

            mockContext.Setup(m => m.Persons).Returns(mockSet.Object);


            var service = new PersonController(mockContext.Object);

            ActionResult person = service.Details(1);


        }
```

[image: The first example in which you can see the data]

[image: The second example in which you can no longer see the data]

is there any particular reason for this? because i honestly don't see it. i figured it might be because the moq data only thinks it has to be called once and then dissappears but i have no idea... and i did check the data and saw that the ID that is given (1) is added to 1 of the objects and it's also visible in that passed on list

thanks in advance, 
Marijn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using one `IEnumerator` in your mocked object. This means that when your code is through enumerating over the items in it, it's at the end of the `IEnumerator`, and subsequent evaluation of the enumerator will yield 0 results (since it's at the end).

You should be able to fix this just by returning a new `IEnumerator` every time `GetEnumerator` is called:

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());
```

Or, reuse the same enumerator, but reset it each time it's accessed:

```
var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();

mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() =>
    {
        enumerator.Reset();
        return enumerator;
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot that did solve my problem that i can enumarate multiple times but sadly it still can't find the object :(

Comment: @Marijn: Did you try mocking the `Find` method so that it returns the person you want?

Comment: that's kind of the problem the Find method is of Dbset<TEntity> that is within the dll for the framework so i can't access it... they only way i think it's possible is because i moq the primary key he can't find it

Comment: @Marijn: You should be able to write `mockSet.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(test1)` (assuming you always want to return the `test1` person for any integer that's passed in)

Comment: well no i want it return the person with the ID passed on so if it's 1 i want test if it's 2 i want test1 and if it's 3 i want test2

Comment: @Marijn: Well the idea of mocking an object is that you take control over how it works completely for the purposes of your unit test. So if you're testing the `Details` action, you'd force `.Find` to return something specific that you want in your test. Nevertheless, you could also provide your own implementation of `.Find`, something like `mockSet.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(id => data.SingleOrDefault(item => item.ID == id));`

Comment: yes you indeed gave me an idea and now it works tyvm :) i'm quite new to Linq so i should probably study that a bit better :P